# I want to move the elements inside multiple list of arrays around

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have this array

```
0: (5) ["2", "X", "8", "11", "15"] 
1: (5) ["1", "5", "X", "X", "14"]
2: (5) ["X", "4", "7", "10", "13"]
3: (5) ["X", "3", "6", "9", "12"]
```

I want to move the digit 1 to the position where digit 2 is so that this array will return

```
0: (5) ["1", "X", "8", "11", "15"]
1: (5) ["2", "5", "X", "X", "14"]
2: (5) ["X", "4", "7", "10", "13"]
3: (5) ["X", "3", "6", "9", "12"]
```

This collection of array is returned all at once, so I will like to change the position once it's returned.

I am using JavaScript.
Thanks everyone.

I tried

```
Array.prototype.move = function (from, to) {
this.splice(to, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]);
};
```

But this moves the entire row with each other i.e moves array 0 to array 1

Answer (score 1):

Find the outer array index and the inner array index of both, then switch them:

```js
const input = [
 ["2", "X", "8", "11", "15"] ,
 ["1", "5", "X", "X", "14"],
 ["X", "4", "7", "10", "13"],
 ["X", "3", "6", "9", "12"]
];

const getLoc = char => {
  const arrIndex = input.findIndex(subarr => subarr.includes(char));
  const subArrIndex = input[arrIndex].indexOf(char);
  return [arrIndex, subArrIndex];
};
const move = (char1, char2) => {
  const [loc1, loc2] = [char1, char2].map(getLoc);
  
  [
    // switch position of first character:
    input[loc1[0]][loc1[1]],
    // and position of second character:
    input[loc2[0]][loc2[1]]
  ] = [
    // with position of second character:
    input[loc2[0]][loc2[1]],
    // and the first character:
    input[loc1[0]][loc1[1]]
  ];
};

move('2', '1');
console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findIndex` to find the first index of `2` and `1` from their respective array and then replace it. Else if you are looking to replace element only at specific index then you can directly target the array and index and replace it

```js
let data = [
  ["2", "X", "8", "11", "15"],
  ["1", "5", "X", "X", "14"]
];


let find2In1 = data[0].findIndex(item => item === "2");
let find1In2 = data[1].findIndex(item => item === "1");
data[0][find2In1] = "1";
data[1][find1In2] = "2";

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work but now, you are specifying the value itself.
What if the numbers are the same like this example, and I want to move the character in the first to the second like this one below:
0: (5) [2, -1, 0, 0, 0]
1: (5) [0, 2, -1, -1, 2]
2: (5) [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3: (5) [-1, 2, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve it by creating another vector function and it should return return [1, 0]; cause i noticed when I pass 2 and 0 to the switchVectorValues it always selects the first row to alter both values, so since I know the row i want to swap, I just specified it in the vector return value.

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your sample, looks like that you need to alternate 1 and 2.

Input

```
0: (5) ["2", "X", "8", "11", "15"] 
1: (5) ["1", "5", "X", "X", "14"]
2: (5) ["X", "4", "7", "10", "13"]
3: (5) ["X", "3", "6", "9", "12"]
```

Output

```
0:(5) ["1", "X", "8", "11", "15"]
1: (5) ["2", "5", "X", "X", "14"]
2: (5) ["X", "4", "7", "10", "13"]
3: (5) ["X", "3", "6", "9", "12"]
```

You can search through each array and do this using forEach.

```
a.forEach((item) => {

   if (item === "1")
      item = "2"
   else
      if (item === "2")
          item = "1"
})
```